# Run a NODE application and Host a website without internet nor server

Tags: node.js, router, local, web-hosting

**Background:**
In our country at our facilities, we do not always have internet.
In addition, we try not to install Windows servers because we do not have the man power nor knowledge to maintain the Windows machines.

We do have a WIFI network.
We use these routers from gl-inet.com to create a mesh.
These routers can be configured to serve a static website from a USB drive inserted into the back of the router.

All this works great, however, I would like to add a background Node app to maintain and update the content when there is internet.

**QUESTION:**
So, I need a NON-Windows device, that can run a Node application and host a static website.

Is there a small cheap device that I can sick on my network to run my application?

I have considered a Raspberry Pi, but my boss would prefer a ready made solution.

Comment: That is a question about hardware, not software, so it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Agreed, but where else would I ask such a question. I would hope my fellow developers would know some suggestions.

Comment: I'm not a specialist but there seems to be a community: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/